# Pass inner template class as template argument in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to pass an inner template class (of a regular class) to another class that accepts templates as arguments.

The class that accepts templates is:

```
template <typename... T> struct TypeList {
  template <template <typename...> typename P> using Apply = P<T...>;
};
```

So when I have something like `using List = TypeList<int, float, double>;` I can do

```
static_assert(std::is_same<List::template Apply<std::tuple>,
                           std::tuple<int, float, double>>::value);
```

But if I change `std::tuple` so an inner template class, it stops working. I.e.,

```
struct Outer {
  template <typename... P> struct Inner {};
};

static_assert(std::is_same<List::template Apply<typename Outer::Inner>,
                           Outer::Inner<int, float, double>>::value);
```

doesn't work.

My compiler complains about

> error: invalid use of template-name ‘Outer::Inner’ without an argument list

It works if I "flatten" the inner template class with `template <typename... P> using Flat = Outer::Inner<P...>;`.

My question is, is there a way to make the inner template class work, without aliasing it and flattening it? Am I missing the `typename` or `template` keyword somewhere?

Complete example is:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... T> struct TypeList {
  template <template <typename...> typename P> using Apply = P<T...>;
};

struct Outer {
  template <typename... P> struct Inner {};
};

template <typename... P> using Flat = Outer::Inner<P...>;

int main() {
  using List = TypeList<int, float, double>;
  static_assert(std::is_same<List::template Apply<std::tuple>,
                             std::tuple<int, float, double>>::value);
  static_assert(std::is_same<List::template Apply<Flat>,
                             Outer::Inner<int, float, double>>::value);
  static_assert(std::is_same<List::template Apply<typename Outer::Inner>,
                             Outer::Inner<int, float, double>>::value);
}
```

Comment: Earlier you said [my solution](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6650258f7578eb9e) was incorrect. Can you explain how? Getting rid of the `typename` keyword made all 3 asserts pass and compile.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Sorry, your solution was correct. But I had a slightly more complex case and the compiler is giving the same error on my code. The more rigorous solution is to specify `Outer::template Inner` and that satisfies the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typename Outer::Inner` is wrong as `Inner` is not a type but a template.

You can even remove all typename/template here as there is no dependent type issue.

```
static_assert(std::is_same<List::Apply<Outer::Inner>,
                           Outer::Inner<int, float, double>>::value);
```

In dependent context, it would be

```
// template <typename OuterT> /*..*/
static_assert(std::is_same<List::Apply<OuterT::template Inner>,
                           typename OuterT::template Inner<int, float, double>>::value);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/SZAX7z)

Comment: I believe I had a faithful repro but removing all typename/template didn't do it. But it all worked when I followed the solution for dependent context (i.e., being super explicit about template vs typename)